# Confusion with weights dumping from neural net in keras

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, keras

I created a simple 2-layer network, one hidden layer. I am dumping the weights from the middle layer to visualize what the hidden neurons are learning.
I am using

```
weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()
```

When I look at the weights structure I get:

So `len(weights) = 2`, `len(weights[0]) = 500`, `len(weights[1]) = 100`.

I want to create an array m of size `(500,100)`, so that `m.shape = (500,100)`.
I tried `numpy.reshape(weights, 500, 100)`, `zip(weights[0], weights[1])`, then, by chance, I wrote `numpy.array(weights[0])` and this came back with shape `(500,100)`.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: I have an understanding, for validation please let me know what does `len(weights[0][0])` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Keras tensors work differently, they are n-dimensional lists. To illustrate the concept consider the list:

```
>>> list=[[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[1,2,3]]
```

Here, the first element in list contains n-length elements and second list can also be an n-length elements. When you do:

```
>>> len(list)
```

Output is:

```
2( which is 2 in your case)
```

Also,

```
>>> len(list[0])

5(which is 500 in your case)

>>> len(list[1])

3(which is 100 in your case)
```

But when you try to convert to array:

```
>>> np.array(list[0]).shape
```

The answer is:

```
(5, 3) (which is 500,100 in your case)
```

This is because you are having an n-length list element inside your list[0] (which is weights[0] in your case). So when I asked you to return

```
len(weights[0][0])
```

it returned:

```
100
```

because it contains 100 length elements in that list and 500 such elements in it. Now, if you are wondering what does each 100 values mean, so they are corressponding weights of the connections i.e.

```
weights[0][0] = weights between first input to all 100 hidden neurons
```

Comment: Thank you. My list comes from dumping the weights of a neural net using keras list = model.layers[0].get_weights().

Comment: So are you dumping the weights from your input layer? Is it a convolutional neural network or simple back propagation? What is the neural net architecture? Also, please edit the question because this is entirely different question.

Comment: I did not think it was related to keras but maybe it is. I edited my question.

Comment: So weights[0] is the matrix I am looking for, the 500by300 weight matrix between the two layers, and weights[0][i] is the 500 vector of weights to the i neuron in the second layer. Correct?